# Ubuntu 20 can't uninstall mysql server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dpkg, systemctl

I was trying to uninstall mysql using apt-get purge mysql-server but uninstall was not sucessfull and now it blocks installation of mariadb.

```
petter@server:~$ sudo dpkg -P --force-all mysql-server-8.0
(Reading database ... 71256 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--purge):
    installed mysql-server-8.0 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error                                                                                                                                                       exit status 1
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
    installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned                                                                                                                                                       error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
    mysql-server-8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Some missing files maybe, try reinstalling it first with `--reinstall` and then prune it again

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got error E: Internal Error, No file name for mysql-server-8.0:amd64. But thanks for help :)

Comment: Try using `apt install mysql-server-8.0 --reinstall`

Comment: Did you find an answer; I'm having the same struggle.